# Tree Traversal. Pre- and Postorder for general trees, inorder only for binary trees?

Tags: tree, traversal, inorder, preorder, postorder

I read that preorder and postorder traversal were also defined for general (n-ary) trees like that:

```
preOrder(v)
  if(v==null) return;
  print(v)
  for each child w of v
     preOrder(w)

postOrder(v)
  if(v==null) return;
  for each child w of v
     postOrder(w)
  print(v)
```

But inorder traversal ist just for binary trees. Why I cant make an inOrder traversal method like the pre and postOrder examples shown above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can of course define a traversal that is an *n*-ary generalisation of what *inorder* is for binary trees.

For binary trees *inorder* means visiting a node after its left child is visited, but before its right child is visited.

For *n*-ary, you could for instance say a node should be visited after its *k* leftmost children have been visited, and before any other of its children. *k* would be a predefined constant, and when *k*=1, and your tree happens to be binary, then you have the same traversal as the classic *inorder* traversal.

```
inOrder(k, v)
  if(v==null) return;
  for each child w among the first k children of v:
      inOrder(k, w)
  print(v)
  for each child w not among the first k children of v:
      inOrder(k, w)
```

But as you can see, this is a bit of a clumsy traversal, and one could wonder if there is really a practical use for it.

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But why is an inorder traversal for a n-ary tree not usefull or clumsy in contrast to pre- and postorder traversal?

Comment: That is just a personal opinion... I mean it is quite arbitrary to choose a *k*, and then I wonder which practical use such a traversal would have. I cannot think of any.

Comment: OK. Thanks. Which practical use have pre- and post order for n-ary trees?

Comment: An example where preorder is practical, is extending each node with the distance it has to the root of the tree. An example where postorder is practical, is extending each node with the height of its subtree. In binary trees the inorder traversal is practical in case it concerns a search tree.

Comment: To expand on this answer: If we call the generalized `inOrder` suggested by trincot "in-_k_-order" then preorder would be called "in-0-order", postorder (for an _n_-ary tree) would be called "in-_n_-order". For a 2-ary (binary) tree, pre- and postorder is "in-0-order" and "in-2-order" respectively. There is thus a "natural choice" for _inorder_ which is "in-1-order". For an _n_-ary tree, there are several inorder candidates: "in-1-order", "in-2-order", ..., "in-(_n_-1)-order". Which one to chose is, as trincot put it, quite arbitrary.

Comment: @knowledge please accept this answer if you think it answers your question. Also, go back to your previous questions and accept answers where appropriate.